# Tkinter Progressbar Movement Speed Change?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

It is possible to change the movement speed of Tkinter progressbar when configured in *indeterminate* state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an elegant way, in case anyone is still looking.

The *.start()* method on a ttk.Progressbar can accept an argument to specify the interval in milliseconds.

> ***.start([interval])***
>
> Start moving the indicator every interval milliseconds; the default is 50ms. Each time, the indicator is moved as if you called the .step() method.

Here's the sample code to try it yourself:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

p10 = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode='indeterminate', length=200)
p10.pack()
p10.start(10)

p100 = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode='indeterminate', length=200)
p100.pack()
p100.start(100)

p1000 = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode='indeterminate', length=200)
p1000.pack()
p1000.start(1000)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `after(milliseconds, function_name)` to run periodically own function which will use `step()` to change value in progressbar. If you use different `milliseconds` or different value in `step()` then it will move with different speed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def change():
    p.step(10)
    root.after(100, change) # run again after 100ms,

root = tk.Tk()

p = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode='indeterminate')
p.pack()

change() # run first time 

root.mainloop()
```